# How can I log on which Thread this log line executed?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance, debugging

I want to make common method for logging on which thread current method is executed without debugging and manage maximum tasks in background or on worker thread.

Can anyone help please? this can help many developers if we can do it by some way.

What I have tried is:

1. Debug the lines where I want to find on which thread it is executing. e.g. in below screenshot it is executing on UI thread.
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use `Thread.currentThread()`:

```
 public class Main{

   public static void main(final String[] args) {
      someMethod();
   }

   public static void someMethod() {
      log("hello from someMethod");
      //do stuff
   }

   public static void log(final String msg) {
      final String threadname = Thread.currentThread().getName();
      System.out.println( "[" + threadname + "] " + msg );
   }
}
```

But I suggest to take a look at [log4j](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_patternlayout.htm).